# Trailing zero not displaying when String to Datetime parse in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a string
`var str = "2021-11-19T19:45:30.810Z"` but if I use
`DateTime.TryParse(str,out datefr)`
And pass this datefr value to Api, in log file seeing only
 `"2021-11-19T19:45:30.81+05:30"`
where the millisecond is displaying only as 81 instead of 810.
Is there any way to pass this date along with three digit millisecond(with the trailing zero) to datetime variable

Tried DateTime.ParseExact() but still the trailing zero are not passing

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. What you're seeing depends on how the value is ultimately formatted (*not* on how it's parsed), and you don't show how that happens. Compare `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")` vs. `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFF")`, for example.

Comment: Personally, I would also be a bit more concerned that the value you're parsing has a `Z` time zone indicator (which is UTC) but your server is logging a non-zero offset. Either the `Z` should not be there on parsing if the intent is to use local time, or else `DateTimeOffset` should be used.